# RSA and AES for encrypt and decrypt a plainText (verify key)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I want to ask you some question about security on key in java. My code using RSA and AES for encrypt and decrypt a plainText. And I want to use my own password as a private key(AES) for verifies key(RSA). Because RSA are generate public and private key random. (In real case: private key is input by user and public key store in database for verification.)

This code is work find, but I want to know this code is correct or not? Please advice! Thank you.

My process:
 1. generate a symmetric key
 2. Encrypt the data with the symmetric key
 3. Encrypt the symmetric key with rsa
 4. send the encrypted key and the data
 5. Decrypt the encrypted symmetric key with rsa
 6. decrypt the data with the symmetric key
 7. done

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES_RSA {

    private static byte[] key;
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {

            //1. Generate Symmetric Key (AES with 128 bits)
            String password = "123456";
            KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            generator.init(128); // The AES key size in number of bits

            setKey(password);

            //2. Encrypt plain text using AES
            String plainText = "Please encrypt me urgently...";
            Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());

            //3. Encrypt the key using RSA public key
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

            PublicKey puKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            PrivateKey prKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, puKey);
            byte[] encryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded()/*Seceret Key From Step 1*/);

            //4. Send encrypted data (byteCipherText) + encrypted AES Key (encryptedKey)
            //5. On the client side, decrypt symmetric key using RSA private key
            cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, prKey);
            byte[] decryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);

            //6. Decrypt the cipher using decrypted symmetric key
            SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKey , 0, decryptedKey.length, "AES");
            Cipher aesCipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            aesCipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
            byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher1.doFinal(byteCipherText);
            String plainText1 = new String(bytePlainText);

            //7. Done! 'Please encrypt me urgently...'
            System.out.println(plainText1);

        }catch (Exception e) {}
    }


    public static void setKey(String myKey)
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code works, you should try code review instead.  This is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Also, you don't authenticate your ciphertext at all.  Anyone could change it and you wouldn't know.  You aren't using this in production right?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Does the encrypted secret key need to be authenticated or does it not matter if it's tampered with?

Answer (score 1):

You pseudo-steps are correct, but your description not. For example, you normally keep `RSA` private key and distribute `RSA` public key.

But a few suggestions for creating better code.

1. I suggest to use `PKCS5` for creating password-based secret keys rather than a simple hash. Java's `PBEKeySpec` is a class for generating such secret keys. Here is a small sample code which you can use for your `setKey()` routine (adjust it as you prefer):

   ```
   SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("AES");
   SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.getBytes("UTF-8"), salt, 10000));
   ```
2. Never use `ECB` mode of operation for encrypting data. In worse case, use `CBC` with randomized `IV`.
3. You got something wrong. `RSA` private key is kept private on server, but `RSA` public key is distributed freely between clients(normally). You are doing this in the other way.
4. This is just a suggestion, but I think it is better to use `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` rather than `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` for `RSA` padding. But I think it is not necessary.
5. In general, you must add a hash or `HMAC` for authenticating your encrypted data too. But you don't have any authenticating mechanism right now.

**Update:** Based on design of your mechanism, you cannot securely add an authentication method for detecting active attacks(such as man-in-the-middle). Check comments from Maarten too.

These are the problems that I found. The most important one is just using `RSA` key-pair in an incorrect way.

Comment: ECB and CBC aren't padding modes.  They are modes of operation.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark oops, miss typing. sorry. O.O

Comment: OAEP has more chances of padding oracle attacks such as the Bleichenbacher attacks, so yeah, where possible use that or RSA-KEM (you may need some additional crypto library for KEM). Using a MAC or even authenticated mode of operation is nice, but remember that anybody can encrypt with the public key. So this won't protect you from active attacks. You'll need signature over the plaintext message to avoid that (sign-then-encrypt). The code is not secure for transport mode security; just adding an authentication tag won't do it; using TLS might.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yea, you are write. I'm not sure if it is possible to design a 1-message secure encryption protocol without any preshared symmetric keys. I will update my replay with your comment about authentication.